# What is the name of the widget or design element that shows where you are in the process of filling out a form?

Tags: web, widget

I am pretty sure it has a name other than a progress bar, which shows very fluidly amount loaded or percent complete.  I am not interested in what shows percent complete.  I am looking for the name of a thing that shows you, **in named steps or page numbers**, where you are in filling out a form.

I remember seeing somewhere a line of interlocking arrow-shaped buttons that accomplished this, but the specifics of the graphic representation is not so important to me.  I will experiment with various ways to render this.  But in order for me to research more,... what is this thing called by web developers?

Comment: are you looking for [Wizard Navigation](https://www.google.com/search?q=wizard+navigation)?

Comment: I believe that is it.  Or close.  One of the web sites describes the graphical representation of the user's place in the wizard as a "sequence map," but googling that doesn't turn up a lot.  I guess the graphical element is secondary to the UI Pattern and doesn't really have a codified name because it can be done in so many different ways.  But... thanks!